# Error-invalid length for a base-64 char array

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I have silverlight app that post some data to another web application ,the data to post is converted to base 64 using code

```
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sDataToPost);
sDataToPost = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
```

Another webapplication
get the data using the code

```
strText = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(System.Convert.FromBase64String(postedData));
```

But it gives the exception **invalid length for a base-64 char array**

Thanks in Advance
DNM

Comment: is it encoded which makes it somehow an invalid base64 string?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a few minutes to read the FAQ and the Markdown documentation (a useful synposis of which is available in the right hand margin when editing a question).

Comment: Please show the code you are using to post and also the server-side code which fills the `postedData` variable.  As @Michel points out its possible that further encoding happens. Also why are you decoding with `ASCII` and not `UTF-8` ?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you post the data its quite possible that the Base64 string is being munged a little more.  For example URL encoders may do odd things with the + and = symbols in the Base64 string.